# Proving limit using precise limit definition

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

I would like to prove that $$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 2}\frac{1}{x^2}=\frac{1}{4}
$$ using the epsilon-delta definition of a limit.

I start with the formal definition:

For every $\varepsilon$ > 0 there exist a $\delta$ > 0 such that if $|x - a| < \delta$, then $|f(x) - a|$ < $\varepsilon$.

So I need to prove that if $|x - 2| < \delta$ then $|\frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{4}| < \varepsilon$ .

I start by doing scratch-work to turn the left hand side of $|\frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{4}| < \varepsilon$ into $|x-2|$
$$
|\frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{4}| < \varepsilon
$$
$$
|\frac{4-x^2}{4x^2}| < \varepsilon
$$
$$
|4-x^2| < 4x^2\varepsilon
$$
$$
|(x+2)(x-2)| < 4x^2\varepsilon
$$
$$
|x-2| < \frac{4x^2}{|x+2|}\varepsilon
$$
I would be able to complete the proof if the right-hand side were simply $\frac{\varepsilon}{|x+2|}$, but the $4x^2$ is throwing me off.

Normally I would pick: $\delta \leq 1$ then use $|x-2|<\delta=1$, or $-1<x-2<1$ to turn $x-2$ into the denominator with $\varepsilon$, then pick the lowest bound of the inequality, giving me $\delta = min:\{1, \frac{\varepsilon}{<lowest bound>}\}$

I don't know how to handle the extra $4x^2$ however. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider instead backing up a bit to the point where you had the expression
$$\left\vert \frac{4 - x^2}{4x^2} \right\vert.$$
If you choose $\delta < 1$, then $\vert 4x^2 \vert > 4$, hence we have
$$\left\vert \frac{4 - x^2}{4x^2} \right\vert < \frac{\vert (2 - x)(2 + x) \vert}{4}.$$
Can you finish now?